# SQL Server Partition Switching using Codeplex tool

Tags: sql-server, partitioning, database-partitioning, codeplex

I have partitioned my table correctly. But now I am trying to use [CodePlex SQL Server Partition Management Tool](https://sqlpartitionmgmt.codeplex.com/) to create the staging/archive table for switching the partition.

When I run both `createstagingnoindex` or `CreateStagingClusteredIndex` - all works fine.

However, when I try to either apply indexes (`indexstaging`) or just use `CreateStagingFull` from the outset - I am getting the same error:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an obj  ect.  at
>   PartitionManagement.PartitionManager.createStgIndex(Index i,
>   TableViewBase  parent)  at
>   PartitionManagement.PartitionManager.createStgNonclusteredIndexes() 
>   at PartitionManagement.PartitionManager.CreateStgIndexes(Boolean
>   createNonClu  steredIndexes)  at PartitionManagement.App.Run(AppArgs&
>   parsedArgs)  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.